# Adding border to another class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When clicking on box '1', a border should then appear around box a'.  When clicking on box 'a', a border should appear around box 'b' and so on...
What should the JavaScript look like to accomplish this?

```css
.list-box li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;padding: 2em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin-top: 50px;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;padding: 2em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:100px auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row col-content">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                   <ul class="list-box">
                       <li class="click">1</li>
                       <li class="click">2</li>
                       <li class="click">3</li>
                       <li class="click">4</li>
                   </ul>
                   <div class="txt">some text</div> 
                   <ul class="box-sleeve">
                       <li class="border">a</li>
                       <li class="border">b</li>
                       <li class="border">c</li>
                       <li class="border">d</li>
                   </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </section>
```

Comment: Did you try to write any JS for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating arrays, we can "sync" up the two sets of boxes.

```js
// Get references to the two sets of boxes
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".click");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

// Turn each node list into proper arrays:
numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers);
letters = Array.prototype.slice.call(letters);

// Loop through all the number boxes
numbers.forEach(function(box, index){

  // Set up the click event handlers for all the number boxes
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    // Remove borders from each of the letter boxes
    letters.forEach(function(box){
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });
  
    // Apply the border to only the one clicked element
    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");
  });
});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;padding: 2em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin-top: 50px;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;padding: 2em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:100px auto;}
.showBorder { border: 3px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row col-content">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                   <ul class="list-box">
                       <li class="click">1</li>
                       <li class="click">2</li>
                       <li class="click">3</li>
                       <li class="click">4</li>
                   </ul> 
                   <ul class="box-sleeve">
                       <li class="border">a</li>
                       <li class="border">b</li>
                       <li class="border">c</li>
                       <li class="border">d</li>
                   </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </section>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. what if i only need one highlighted at a time?

Comment: I tried to make it as simplistic as possible for an obvious beginner. I do understand and agree with you though, so I removed my answer.

Comment: Providing quality answers for *zero-research-code-for-me-for-free-questions* makes the web so much better, Scott, which also happens to be [so]'s mission statement. +1 from me.

Comment: @user3767554 Updated answer.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Thanks for doing that. The issue (that many devs don't realize) is that inline HTML attributes are more than just ugly. They can and do actually modify the way code will execute. They should not be used under any circumstances.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for your input on this Scott. one more question - How can i add class="copy" to this scenario to coincide with 'showBorder'

Comment: @user3767554 What does `class=copy` do?

Comment: @user3767554 I'm sorry, I'm not following you. Can you explain (clearly) what you are looking for?

Comment: @ScottMarcus sorry Scott - I want to add a div containing text just above the the box with border, needs to have the same functionality as the border class="showBorder"

Comment: @user3767554 So, when a number box gets clicked, not only will the corresponding letter box below it get a border but also the `div` that is above that?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes when number is selected the letter box below will have a border and some text above it

Comment: @user3767554 To do it would require some revamping of the HTML structure. At that point, I'd be using CSS Flexbox to do the layout with the JavaScript I've got here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus hey! I've edited my html - added a div with class .txt. How do I include that class to show with .showBorder

Comment: @user3767554 Just change the class name from `.txt` to `.showBorder` and duplicate what I've done with the `letters` array with a new array for your text.

Answer (score 0):

We can use jQuery to achieve this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $list = $("ul.list-box");
  var $sleeves = $("ul.box-sleeve");
  var $listLI = $list.children("li");
  var $sleevesLI = $sleeves.children("li");

  $listLI.each(function(index, elem){
    var $curr_li = $listLI.eq(index);//I know you can use $(this) but it's for understanding purpose that I don't use it

    $curr_li.click(function(){
     var $corresponding_sleeveLI = $sleevesLI.eq(index);
     $corresponding_sleeveLI.toggleClass("borderAround");
    });
  });
});
```

And then add this to your CSS :

```
.borderAround{
  border:/*some border settings for when you have those border around*/;
  transition:/*some transition settings if you wanna have any*/;
}
```

EDIT

If you want to only have one box highlighted at a time you can (in the click EH, after or before the `toggleClass`):

```
var $otherB = $sleevesLI.not($corresponding_sleeveLI);
$otherB.each(function(index, elem){
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.hasClass("borderAround")){
    $this.removeClass("borderAround");
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! more than one way to skin a cat is what i keep finding with coding. what if i only need one box highlighted at a time?

Comment: Meaning that if a box is highlighted all other shouldn't ?

Comment: also how easy is it to add some paragraph copy above the border to act the same as the border?